# why "gc.get_objects“ in function will make circular reference or memory leak?

Tags: python-2.7, memory-leaks

this code will make circular reference!,
if object disable automatic garbage collection,"gc.disable()",
running it will make memory leaking!

```
import gc, sys


def test_func():
    objs = gc.get_objects()
    priint("-----End: test_func %s" % sys.getrefcount(test_func))

test_func()
```

l know this is right, but why???

```
import gc, sys


def test_func():
    objs = gc.get_objects()
    del objs
    priint("-----End: test_func %s" % sys.getrefcount(test_func))

test_func()
```

version: 2.7
thank bro!

Answer (score 0):

I knew it

```
case frame in gc.get_objects()


def TestFunc3():
    lst = gc.get_objects()
    print("sys._getframe() in lst: %s" % (sys._getframe() in lst))
    print lst in sys._getframe().f_locals.values()
    
print("--TestFunc3 ref: %s" % sys.getrefcount(TestFunc3))
TestFunc3()
print("--TestFunc3 ref: %s" % sys.getrefcount(TestFunc3))
TestFunc3()
print("--TestFunc3 ref: %s" % sys.getrefcount(TestFunc3))


"""
--TestFunc3 ref: 2
sys._getframe() in lst: True
True
--TestFunc3 ref: 3
sys._getframe() in lst: True
True
--TestFunc3 ref: 4
"""
```